# In UI/UX design, what word in Japanese is used for "mockup"?

Tags: english-to-japanese, terminology

Is there a more standard term than "デザインモックアップ"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Mockup" in this context is normally translated simply as モックアップ (or モック for short) into Japanese. See [example 1](https://ja.react.dev/learn/thinking-in-react#start-with-the-mockup), [example 2](https://mieru-ca.com/heatmap/blog/what-is-mockup/). But it's a relatively new word, and people usually described this as (動かない)デザインサンプル, 外見確認用サンプル or something. For tangible products, we also say (外見確認用の)試作品. Sometimes [ハリボテ](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%BC%B5%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BC%E3%81%A6) is used to refer to a non-working product that looks good, but it's slangy and not very respectful.